# Mysql password no longer working

Tags: mysql, outage

Does anyone know if a power outage could somehow have corrupt the mysql logins? We had an outage the other day, my mysql logins no longer work. The mysql process seems to be running fine.

Any idea how I can recover from my current predicament!

[Edit]

It now seems the user account no longer exists!

[/edit]

Answer (score 3):

The power failure can cause some mysql tables to be marked as corrupted and should be checked. Before that, you will not be able to query such tables. I remember I faced a similar problem of corrupted tables. Most likely, the tables with ongoing updates will suffer from such an error.

I suggest that you restart mysql with the option `--skip-grant-tables` to be able to login. Then, you can check the tables under `mysql` database. Also, you can change any user password.

For MyISAM tables, you can do something like:

```
mysql> repair table <table_name>;
```

Comment: It seems the account in question no longer exists in the user table (I found a debian-sys-maint account in the system dirs).